# Change from GCS region settings to multi-region

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have been trying to see if we should setup a GCS bucket with `region` or `multi-region`. The needs today are regional only.

I am wondering if there is an option to change from `region` only to `multi-region` at a later point in time?

This also saves some `$`'s till we move to `multi-region` setting. Just having it enabled, doesn't help us much today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no one-step solution for moving objects from being regional to multi-regional. If you have a bucket containing a lot of regional objects and you want them to be multi-regional, you'll need to copy them into a new multi-regional bucket. The [Cloud Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/) can manage this for you, or you can do it with gsutil.

You can change a bucket's configuration to cause new objects to have a different storage class, but it won't effect existing objects. Also, this will only help you switching to and from nearline and coldine storage classes, as multi-regional and regional storage classes do not share locations, and bucket locations cannot be changed.